# Unknown cause of Segmentation Fault during destruction of a ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, lock-free

So I was messing around with a ConcurrentQueue (found [here](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue)) and I am stumbling upon a Seg Fault during the destruction of the ConcurrentQueue (Seg Faults at line 3397 of concurrentqueue.h). I tried using the queue in multiple other contexts however its is only causing a Seg Fault while being used in this context (Code below.) (Which is making me wonder if my code is causing this).

```
#ifndef MPSCWORKER_MPSCWORKER_HPP
#define MPSCWORKER_MPSCWORKER_HPP

#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <exception>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

#include "ConcurrentQueue.h"

template <class Type>
class SinkBase;
class SinkNotRegisteredException;

template <class Type, const unsigned int numOfSinks>
class MPSCWorker{

public:
    //Funcs
    MPSCWorker();
    ~MPSCWorker(){

        Type msg = {};
        //Send an empty msg to the reserved channel to say we're done.
        send(msg, numOfSinks + 1);
        if(workerThread.joinable())
            workerThread.join();

        for(int i = 0; i <= numOfSinks + 1; i++){
            if(sinks[i].get() != nullptr){
                sinks[i].get()->onExit();
            }
        }
    }

    void start(){
        isThreadRunning.store(true);
        workerThread = std::thread(run,
                                   std::ref(workQueue),
                                   std::ref(sinks),
                                   std::ref(isThreadRunning),
                                   std::ref(threadCondVar),
                                   std::ref(threadMutex));
    }

    int  addSink(std::unique_ptr<SinkBase<Type>> &&sink, unsigned int sinkID){

        if(!isThreadRunning.load()){
            if(sinkID <= numOfSinks + 1){
                sinks[sinkID] = std::move(sink);
                if(!sinks[sinkID].get()->onInit()){
                    return -3;
                }
            } else{
                return -1;
            }
        }else{
            return -2;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void send(Type msg, unsigned int sinkID){
        workQueue.enqueue(InternalType{msg, sinkID});
        threadCondVar.notify_one();
    }

private:

    //Types
    struct InternalType{
        Type msg;
        unsigned int sinkID;
    };

    //Vars
    std::atomic<bool>                         isThreadRunning;
    std::thread                               workerThread;
    std::condition_variable                   threadCondVar;
    std::mutex                                threadMutex;
    //ID = numOfSinks + 1: reserved
    std::unique_ptr<SinkBase<Type>>           sinks[numOfSinks + 1];
    moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue<InternalType> workQueue;

    //Funcs
    static void run(moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue<InternalType> &workQueue,
                    std::unique_ptr<SinkBase<Type>>           (&sinks)[numOfSinks + 1],
                    std::atomic<bool>                         &isThreadRunning,
                    std::condition_variable                   &threadCondVar,
                    std::mutex                                &threadMutex){

        while(isThreadRunning.load()){

            InternalType                 msg = {};
            bool                         isDequeueSuccess = false;
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(threadMutex);

            threadCondVar.wait(lock, [&workQueue, &msg, &isDequeueSuccess](){
                isDequeueSuccess = workQueue.try_dequeue(msg);
                return isDequeueSuccess;
            });

            if(msg.sinkID == numOfSinks + 1){
                isThreadRunning.store(false);
                return;
            }

            if(sinks[msg.sinkID].get() != nullptr){
                sinks[msg.sinkID].get()->onProcess(msg.msg);
            }else{
                throw SinkNotRegisteredException("Sink ID: " + std::to_string(msg.sinkID)
                                                 + " has not been registered. Use addSink"
                                                 "to associate this ID with a Sink before"
                                                 "starting the worker.");
            }
        }
    }
};

template <class Type, const unsigned int numOfSinks>
MPSCWorker<Type, numOfSinks>::MPSCWorker(){
    isThreadRunning.store(false);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= numOfSinks +1; i++){
        sinks[i] = nullptr;
    }
}


class SinkNotRegisteredException : std::exception{
public:
    SinkNotRegisteredException(std::string msg){this->msg = msg;}
    const char* what(){return msg.c_str();}
    std::string whatStr(){return std::string(msg);}
private:
    std::string msg;
};


template <class Type>
class SinkBase{
public:
    virtual bool onInit()             = 0;
    virtual void onExit()             = 0;
    virtual void onProcess(Type data) = 0;
};

#endif //MPSCWORKER_MPSCWORKER_HPP
```

Here is an example usage of the code above (I know the code is meant for multi-threaded applications but the example is single threaded for simplicity).

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MPSCWorker.hpp"

template <class Type>
class PrintSink : public SinkBase<Type>{
public:
    virtual bool onInit(){return true;}
    virtual void onExit(){}
    virtual void onProcess(Type data){std::cout << data << std::endl;}
};

int main(){

    MPSCWorker<std::string, 1> worker;
    std::unique_ptr<PrintSink<std::string>> sink(new PrintSink<std::string>);
    if(sink.get() == nullptr){
        return -1;
    }
    worker.addSink(std::move(sink), 0);
    worker.start();

    worker.send("test", 0);
    worker.send("test", 0);
    worker.send("test", 0);
    worker.send("test", 0);
    worker.send("test", 0);
    worker.send("test", 0);
    worker.send("test", 0);
    worker.send("test", 0);
    worker.send("test", 0);
    worker.send("test", 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Now the real question is: Is my code causing the Seg Fault? Or is it ConcurrentQueue that is doing something wrong? And in any case, How can this be solved?

Comment: My usual approach to threads/quques/concurrent/anyThingLikeThat is to avoid destroying them at all if possible.  Such things are best destroyed by the OS after it has stopped all the process threads at process shutdown.  I have to admit that this is not such useful advice with C++ - a language that seems built around moving/copying/destroying :(

Comment: Every time I see 'join', 'joinable' and such, it makes me want to turn the page and hide.  It's like inviting a whole party of thirsty vampires in for drinks and snacks:(

Comment: You call `.addSink` *before* `.start()`. In that case (`isThreadRunning.load()` is *false*) it does nothing and returns -2.

Comment: @Tsyvarev `isThreadRunning` is _true_ actually, I guess I forgot to initialize it to false, in any case thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I have found no obvious error in your code, which can lead to Seg Fault. You can try to make your code working with other ConcurrentQueue implementation(e.g. with simple blocking list), and check whether fault disappears. BTW, you implementation of MPSC is not fully correct: it is possible for `threadCondVar.notify_one();` in `send` method to be called **after** `threadCondVar.wait()` in `run` method found predicate to be false, but **before** it goes to wait. So you miss notification. You need to lock mutex for `workQueue.enqueue()` call, `threadCondVar.notify_one();` or just between them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't quite understand what you mean, if `threadCondVar.notify_one();` is called after `threadCondVar.wait()` wouldnt the predicate be _true_ since something was enqueued right before calling the notify? Or am i missing something?...

Comment: Possible scenario: `wait()` checks predicate(under mutex) and found it false(queue is empty) - `.enqueue()` is called - `.notify_one()` is called - worker drops mutex and waits. Using mutex in `.send()` method will make this scenario impossible.